# detect whether the browser supports famo.us

Tags: famo.us, browser-detection, browser-feature-detection

I want to detect whether a visitors browser is capable of running famo.us - if not redirect them.

My first thought was Modernizr and detect whether the browser is capable of CSS 3D transformations, though i'm worried that this may be too severe as famo.us is adding some backward compatibility perhaps through shims.

I'm currently using WURFL for device detection, though this doesn't give enough browser information as far as i can tell.

Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 4):

The standout feature that famo.us depends on is CSS `preserve-3d` which is key to doing CSS 3D transforms and what famo.us depends on to render correctly.

You can use the [**cutting edge**](http://v3.modernizr.com/download/) 3.0 beta of Modernizr to test for this support specifically. I'd recommend using it over reading the User Agent, as you'll always get weird false positives somehow. **Using the current 2.x release will not work**, as `testAllProps` won't support the two parameter syntax.

```
if(Modernizr.testAllProps('transformStyle', 'preserve-3d')){

    //true
    // run famo.us code!
}
else
{
    //false
    // famo.us 3d transforms won't work right, so lets compromise
}
```

There's been quite an effort to track this one on the Modernizr teams part, so if you find any issues, let them know [here](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/issues/762).

Comment: great - will give that a go. Thats exactly what i wanted to know

Comment: i've got this up and running:
ie10 and ie11 do actually work fine with my app - but the above modernizr code rejects those browsers

Comment: Although I haven't needed this information It's very good to know. I'll be +ing the question & the answer. @ amcc I've heard, second hand, that ie can be glitchy and requires really careful testing for edge cases.

Comment: @amcc The test is right to reject IE11 < as preserve-3d isn't implemented, and there are bugs with the implementation of 3d transforms in general right now in IE - though it's being fixed right now according to [modern.ie](http://status.modern.ie/csstransformspreserve3d) A lot of stuff will render fine on IE if you're not actually touching 3D. But IE fails at things like handling backfaces and other things. You're probably looking to first test preserve-3d, and then 3d transforms in general to see if you can run in a crippled form in IE. But it is only IE that's not implemented preserve-3d yet

Comment: Is there a simpler test that will reveal the simpler aspects of what famo.us can do. You're right in that I'm not doing much 3d stuff in IE. I can also see some glitches in IE. But versions 10 and 11 work very well otherwise. Considering the massive amount of famo.us sites/apps that won't need a full 3d experience it's quite promising what IE can do.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do it via user agents to detect browsers and versions. See:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23219710/famo-us-browsers-supports

https://github.com/Famous/famous

Comment: thanks for the help - i saw that other post before, i'm wondering if we can simply look for a browser feature that will signify if famo.us will work, do very old versions of firefox, safari and chrome really work (they've all been around for a while)? Also right now that would exclude all IE.